# How can I enrich my logs with resource file key using serilog?

Tags: logging, serilog

I have a configuration like this:

```
 logObj = new LoggerConfiguration()
               .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(logLevel)
               .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
               .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
               .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
               .Enrich.FromLogContext()
               .Enrich.WithThreadId()
               .WriteTo.File(new Helpers.CompactJsonFormatter(),
               Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\Logs\system_logs\" + StaticVariables.ActiveChannel.ToString()
               + @"\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd/") + ".txt",
               rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Hour,
               levelSwitch: StaticVariables.logLevel
               ).CreateLogger();
```

I want my log codes added by default in my logs. As example I have logs similar to these below:

- ERR0007 — Detailed error message..
- INF0128 — Some info log context..

Is it possible to parse these logs by default so I will have a property called "logCode" or something in my log output.

The main reason why I *think* I need this is for filtering and querying in case I need statistics of my logs.

**Side note:**

I take these logs from a resource file and below you can see a basic sample of it. I'm sharing this because maybe it is possible to take this property out of key instead of parsing the value?

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| ERR0007 | Detailed error message.. |
| INF0128 | Some info log context.. |

I'm also wondering if my approach is correct on this. Taking logs from a resource file and trying to implement the key as property **or** parsing the value to have the code from my template.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialise logger pass Api key

```
.writeTo(seq("http://localhost:5341/","kjhoqmxMUD03RMSj3PXr"))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).